Why is Hikaru a cat instead of a dog?
In Magic Knight Rayearth, Hikaru is often depicted with cat ears and tail. These scenes with her like this are not meant to literally mean she has these anatomical features, but rather are used for some symbolic effect or meaning. This meaning is not entirely clear to me, however.
Why a cat instead of a dog? Hikaru has a dog named Hikari and seems to love dogs. And though I haven't seen this in the story myself, her Fandom Wiki page says she wants to be a dog trainer. And to me, her personal traits seem closer to those attributed to dogs rather than cats. For instance, she's fiercely loyal and enthusiastic, as well as brave, since she is always ready to charge into danger if she needs to help her friends.
Admittedly, the ears and tail aren't so distinct that they couldn't be a dog's. But the onomatopoeia used on page 88 in Part One: Book Two is "MROW!" so I do think they're supposed to be a cat's (If it makes a difference, I'm going by Kodansha's 2024 English reprint).
I'm not fully versed in all the traits associated with cats and dogs, particularly in Japanese culture, so it could be that I'm missing something.
What cat-like traits does Hikaru have? Or what other reason could CLAMP have for depicting her as a cat?
